# How to break a text in `\verb| |` mode

Tags: verbatim

Let's say I have strings of symbols that are not in math mode but I'm trying to define kind of a language that is going to be used in a protoboard. So I have to explain how this language works but for long instructions like for example: `\verb|chain[x,y](newposition[amp, speed](positioning[long, stop, fullview]()))` I don't know how to break it so it stays inside the space defined by `\textwidht` and starting a new line if necessary.

Comment: Is `\texttt{}` an option to you?

Comment: `\verb` never breaks its contents across lines; but if you don't need special characters such as braces or backslash, you just want `\texttt{...}` instead of `\verb`.

Comment: Seems to me that you should look into using [the `listings` package](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/listings/listings.pdf).

Comment: Thank you guys, your comments are very helpful. I think `\texttt{...}`  serves the purpose. There's some extra work though now that I think about it because I need to include some code from MS Excel as it uses symbols like $ and {}.